# Use Blender's bpy in projects outside Blender?

Tags: python

How can I use Blender's `bpy` outside Blender? I need to use it in a project to check for some Blender settings in a `.blend`-file and to automatically start rendering. Since it should completely stand-alone I don't want to set up any paths.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way is to use blender. You can start it with [cli options](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/command_line/arguments.html) to run in the background (without gui) and to run a python script.

```
blender --background --python myscript.py
```

You can also start rendering from the cli without a script.

```
blender -b mymodel.blend --render-frame 1
```

or render an animation

```
blender -b mymodel.blend --frame-start 1 --frame-end 100 --render-anim
```

For something more interactive you can use blenders built-in python console

```
blender -b --python-console
```

The other option to get access to bpy without a normal blender install means you will need to compile your own copy of [blender as a pymodule](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule).

Comment: The `blender` command can only be run if you're in the folder where Blender is installed (if you don't use paths, of course). So let's say I have a copy of Blender in my projects folder; how can use the `blender` command?

Comment: If the system can't find `blender` in it's search of known commands, you need to provide a path that will allow it to be found. If it is in the current dir, then `./blender` can be used on *nix systems, other OS's vary. Everything else remains the same, with the exception of finding scriptand blend files that you specify by name or path.